# Base64 decoding in ITK 4.7 for Dicom

Tags: dicom, itk

I'm converting some legacy code to ITK 4.7 for dicom manipulation. I'm reading private image tags but getting results in Base64 encoded format for few private tags.

I wondered about the value I'm getting for a tag as

```
MlwtNVwyNSA=
```

Basically it is encoded value for

`2\-5\25` `(in base64)`

I know there is Base64.h that comes with gdcm library but question is is that header/functions part of ITK as well or do i need to create gdcm objects to convert the encoded values? or write my own C++ function for that conversion?
What shall be the most efficient (if not native) way within ITK 4.7 library?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the source code (gdcmBase64.h and .cxx), gdcm::Base64 is a self-contained class, which is independent from the rest of GDCM. Just `#include "gdcmBase64.h"`, and call Encode and Decode as needed.

Alternatively, you can find implementations of base64 encoding and decoding and put them in your source file. base64 encoding is pretty simple.

Comment: Looks like that is the only viable option, I thought that since I'm using itk::GDCMImageIO *object, i can call encoding/decoding directly. Thanks for your suggestion anyways. I wonder why GDCMImageIO object doesn't wrap everything.

Comment: Probably because tag values can contain NULLs, which can be problematic if you view the tag value as a null-terminated string.